# не обновляется foreign key в дочерней таблице

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Есть две таблицы, в главной таблице есть столбец `name`, который является ключем для дочерней таблицы.
Когда я обновляю `name`, делаю это так:

```
// перезаписываем данные обьекта
public static void reloadObject(String oldName, String newName, String description, String date, Context context) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    ObjectDB objectDB = new ObjectDB(context);
    SQLiteDatabase db = objectDB.getWritableDatabase();
    cv.put(ObjectDB.objColumn.NAME, newName);
    cv.put(ObjectDB.objColumn.DESCRIPTION, description);
    cv.put(ObjectDB.objColumn.START_DATE, date);
    db.update(ObjectDB.dbTab.OBJECT, cv, ObjectDB.objColumn.NAME + " = ?", new String[]{oldName});
    db.close();
}
```

в дочерней таблице этот столбец не обновляется, хотя в настройках таблицы указано:

```
[object] TEXT REFERENCES geology_object([name]) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Если обновить значение `name` в программе `SQLite Expert Personal` то все корректно обновляется.
Использую готовую базу данных и вставляю ее в проект с помощью `Android SQLiteAssetHelper`

Answer (score 4):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, может кому-то пригодится.
Нужно было вставить эту строчку:

```
db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
```

перед

```
db.update(ObjectDB.dbTab.OBJECT, cv, ObjectDB.objColumn.NAME + " = ?", new String[]{oldName});
```

и все заработало.

Answer (score 2):

Я применяю немного другой способ. Перегружаю метод `SQLiteOpenHelper.onOpen()`

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    super.onOpen(database);
    database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
}
```

тоже работает, причем метод более универсальный, поскольку `setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled()` работает только с API 16